# Add debug code to error messages in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, error-handling

In Matlab, I often have to work with matrices coming from another person's code, and there's not always a clear convention on the orientation of the matrices (transposed or not) and if a certain row/column is added. Therefore I spend much of my time debugging the following error

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

And similar errors for `+`,`.*`,`-`,etc.

It would save me a lot of time if I could modify this error message to include the dimensions, so that I know which one to switch, and potentially guess where the wrong dimension got into.  Hence, I would like to somehow modify the error message to include the dimensions at hand:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree: 243 x 23 and 98 x 23.
```

Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it? I currently spend a lot of time adding/removing/testing debug code that prints out this info, so any solution that brings this any closer would be helpful!

Comment: Modifying the actual error message is possible (I think), by finding the .m file of the matrix-multiplication function and then searching for the error output within that code and include the `size()` for both matrices.

Comment: Use `dbstop if error` and Matlab will stop execution exactly where the error occurs. You can see the variable sizes in the variable browser and directly try out your improved code.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `dbstop if error`, very useful command!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each arithmetic operator in Matlab has an [associated method](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/arithmetic-operators.html) that gets called when you invoke that operator. For example, the method corresponding to `*` (matrix multiplication) is called [`mtimes`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html).

For each operator, you can define a method for variables of type `double` that **shadows** the builtin method and modifies its behaviour: in your case, include custom error checking and then call the builtin method.

The advantages of this approach are:

- **No modification in your code is neccessary**: you will use `*`, `*.`, `+` etc normally; but their (error-checking) behaviour will change.
- When (you think) you're done debugging, you only need to remove your custom methods from the path. This will **restore normal behaviour and thus avoid any speed penalty**. Later, if you need to debug again, all you need to do is place the modified methods back on the path.

In the following I use `*` and its associated `mtimes` as an example. Your new `mtimes` method should be placed in Matlab's path, in an appropriate folder so that it has precedence over the bulitin `mtimes`. That means the folder should be up in Matlab's [`path`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html). Or you can use the current folder, which has precedence over all others.

Within the selected folder create a folder called `@double`, and in it create a file called `mtimes.m`. This tells Matlab that your `mtimes.m` file should be used whenever the `*` is invoked with `double` inputs.

The contents of `mtimes.m` whould be something along the following lines:

```
function C = mtimes(A,B)
if ndims(A)~=2 || ndims(B)~=2
    %// number of dimensions is incorrect
    error('MATLAB:mtimes_modified:ndims', ...
        'One of the arrays is not a matrix: numbers of dimensions are %i and %i',...
        ndims(A), ndims(B));
elseif max(size(A))>1 & max(size(B))>1 size(A,2)~=size(B,1)
    %// dimensions are not appropriate for matrix multiplication,
    %// or for multiplying by a matrix by a scalar
    error('MATLAB:plus_modified:dimagree',...
        'Sizes do not match: %i x %i and %i x %i', ...
        size(A,1), size(A,2), size(B,1), size(B,2));
else
    C = builtin('mtimes', A, B); %// call actual mtimes to multiply matrices
end
```

Example results:

```
>> rand(3,4,5)*rand(6,7)
Error using  *  (line 3)
One of the arrays is not a matrix: numbers of dimensions are 3 and 2 

>> rand(3,4)*rand(2,5)
Error using  *  (line 7)
Sizes do not match: 3 x 4 and 2 x 5 

>> rand(3,4)*rand(4,2)
ans =
    0.3162    0.3009
    1.2628    0.7552
    1.2488    0.8559
```

Comment: have read about that somewhere long time ago, but to me your answer is the first concrete example. highly recommended!!!

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [`try-catch` block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html):

```
a = rand(12);
b = rand(10);

try
    c = a*b;
catch err
    % Because err is read-only, generate new error structure
    % We can copy most of old one

    newerr.identifier = err.identifier;
    newerr.cause = err.cause;
    newerr.stack = err.stack;
    newerr.message = sprintf('%s size(a): [%u, %u] size(b): [%u, %u]', err.message, size(a), size(b));
    error(newerr) % Throw new error
end
```

Now we get:

```
Error using testcode (line 5)
Inner matrix dimensions must agree. size(a): [12, 12] size(b): [10, 10]
```

Comment: But then you need to do all this every time you need to multiply matrices? Wouldn't it be better to place this in a function?

Comment: @LuisMendo It's just an example, the user can implement it however they would like.

Answer (score 2):

If you must do it with many calculations of matrices, then you can write functions like this for example:

```
function C = matproduct(A, B)
try
    C = A * B;
catch ME
    switch ME.identifier
        case 'MATLAB:dimagree'
            msg = [ME.message, ' Size of ', inputname(1), ' :', num2str(size(A)), '. Size of ', inputname(2), ' :', num2str(size(B)), '.'];
        case 'MATLAB:innerdim'
            msg = [ME.message, ' Size of ', inputname(1), ' :', num2str(size(A)), '. Size of ', inputname(2), ' :', num2str(size(B)), '.'];
        % other cases and corresponding modified msg here
    end
    throw(MException(ME.identifier, msg));
end
end
```

However i'm not sure if it affects the speed ... And if you use it as `matproduct(matproduct(a, b), c)` for `a * b * c` for example, then name of the 1st input cannot be displayed.